# Fix css display problems in dd-content of Nestable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use [Nestable](https://dbushell.com/Nestable/) plugin and I have some display problems. Can someone say best way to fix next problem...

You can find my code here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NogerbekNurzhan/uw14y9Lm/)

I want to show in `.dd-content` block text and buttons on the right side in one line. The text sometimes can be too long as you can see and in that case user see such display problems. I tried to use next style to `.dd-handle-title` but works only `white-space`.

```
.dd-handle-title{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I want to show to user something like this:

```
|Teeeeext...[btn][btn][btn]| <-- .dd-content
```

Also the main thing to make this block responsive. I would be grateful for any hints and refactoring! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check this out https://jsfiddle.net/uw14y9Lm/2/

I used flex for handling it

css would look like

```
.right-buttons {
  display: flex;
}
.dd-handle-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.dd3-content {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Hello, my friend! :) Thank you for you answer. You solution is responsive but something wrong with second item. In the right side of Collapse/Expand button is empty space. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek yes, you can remove `margin-right: 9px;` in `.dd-item > button`

Comment: Thank you, bro! ;) Can I ask you one more question cause I still have problem with second item. Text inside second item is shifted little bit. It happens cause `.dd-content` has next style: `padding: 5px 10px 5px 40px;`. I can change this style to `padding: 5px 10px;` and second items' text will be great but in this case first items' text will be shifted. What can you advice? It seems to me I need reorganize code little bit.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/uw14y9Lm/4/ , [data-action="expand"] ~ .dd3-content {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

Comment: Thank you, bro! =)

Answer (score 0):

Done Please check

https://jsfiddle.net/uw14y9Lm/3/

```css
.dd-handle-title{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(25%);
    width: 72%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hello, my friend! :) Thank you for you answer. I test it but problem is that your solution is not responsive. For example when user change the browser size the text appears above the buttons. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?